# Reshape array on xAxis and fill with mean value in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i'm trying to reshape a array in Python and fill it with mean values.
Example:

- Given array: [2, 3, -20, 10, 4]
- Searched array: [2, 2.5, 3, -8.5, -20,
  -5, 10, 7, 4]

More advanced: I've got an array with e.g 1000 samples. But I know it should be 1300 samples long. How to scale the the array to the new length and fill it well distributed with mean values?
A solution with interpolation could make me happy too

---

Edit:
I was questioned for an example what i mean with *well distributed values*. E.g: a sensor should deliver data with 100Hz. But sometimes the sensor is not able to provide the full sampling frequency. Instead of getting 1300 samples in 13 seconds i get a random amount between 900 and 1300 samples. I don't know when a value is missing. I want to distribute the missing values uniformly over the whole array and assign them a meaningful value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a solution which is even better for me. I had some problems with floating errors on large arrays. 
To correct those i inserted some missing ones randomly. Maybe someone knows how to avoid this
I'm sure the code is very optimizable feel free to do this.

```
import numpy as np
def resizeArray(data, newLength):

    datalength = len(data)
    if (datalength == newLength): return data

    appendIndices = []
    appendNow = 0
    step = newLength / datalength
    increase =  step % 1
    for i in np.arange(0, datalength-2, step):
        appendNow += increase
        if appendNow >= 1:
            appendIndices.append(round(i,0))
            appendNow = appendNow % 1

    #still missing values due to floating errors?
    diff = newLength - datalength - len(appendIndices)
    if diff > 0:
        for i in range(0, diff):
            appendIndices.append(np.random.randint(1, datalength - 2))

    #insert average at the specified indizes
    appendVals = [(data[i] + data[i+1]) / 2 for i in appendIndices]
    a = np.insert(data, appendIndices, appendVals)

    return a
```

Comment: Are you sure? First of all, this doesn't run. Some syntax errors, some undefined variables . And secondly, what `Imputer` does is that it replaces *missing values* with the mean over the whole array. This is meant for machine learning algorithms which cannot deal with missing data. It does not achieve what you described in your question.

Comment: i was just editing the code as you wrote the comment. I fixed the errors

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by *well distributed values*. Assuming your values lie on an evenly spaced grid the following solution using interpolation could make sense:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> new_length = 9
>>> b = np.interp(np.linspace(0,len(a)-1,new_length),range(len(a)),a)
>>> b
array([  2. ,   2.5,   3. ,  -8.5, -20. ,  -5. ,  10. ,   7. ,   4. ])
```

This will also work if `len(a)=1000` and `new_length=1300`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a differentiation trick here with [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). Thus, assuming `A` as the input array, you can do  -

```
out = np.empty(2*A.size-1)
out[0::2] = A
out[1::2] = (np.diff(A) + 2*A[:-1]).astype(float)/2 # Interpolated values
```

The trick here is that the differentiation between two consecutive elements when added with twice of the previous element would be the mean value between those two elements. We just use this trick throughout the extent of the input 1D array to get our desired *interpolated* array.

Sample run -

```
In [34]: A
Out[34]: array([  2,   3, -20,  10,   4])

In [35]: out = np.empty(2*A.size-1)
    ...: out[0::2] = A
    ...: out[1::2] = (np.diff(A) + 2*A[:-1]).astype(float)/2
    ...: 

In [36]: out
Out[36]: array([  2. ,   2.5,   3. ,  -8.5, -20. ,  -5. ,  10. ,   7. ,   4. ])
```

---

I think [`@thomas's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962001/3293881) would be the go-to approach here as we are basically doing interpolation with a specific case in mind. But since, I am mostly interested in the performance of codes, here's a runtime test comparing these two solutions -

```
In [62]: def interp_based(A):   # @thomas's solution
    ...:    new_length = 2*A.size-1
    ...:    return np.interp(np.linspace(0,len(A)-1,new_length),range(len(A)),A)
    ...: 
    ...: def diff_based(A): 
    ...:    out = np.empty(2*A.size-1)
    ...:    out[0::2] = A
    ...:    out[1::2] = (np.diff(A) + 2*A[:-1]).astype(float)/2
    ...:    return out
    ...: 

In [63]: A = np.random.randint(0,10000,(10000))

In [64]: %timeit interp_based(A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 932 µs per loop

In [65]: %timeit diff_based(A)
10000 loops, best of 3: 148 µs per loop
```

Comment: The problem is, that your solution only works with an array length divisible by 2 or an even number. If i have an array with 10 entries and i want to have 13 entries, where do i insert the mean values?

Comment: @maniac Mean between consecutive elements, right? In that case, you would have exactly 2*N-1 number of elements, where N is the number of elements in the input. So, with 10 elements, you would have 19 output elements, unless I misunderstood your idea of "inserting mean". Could you list such a sample case with 10 input elements and 13 output elements?