# Reshaping data samples

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sample of data pairs in two arrays. For example:

```
times = [0, 1, 3, 3.5, 5, 6]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So at time 0, the value is 1, at time 1 it is 2 and so on. As you can see the time values are not in regular time distances (though ordered ascending in all cases). I'm seeking for an efficient way to convert the above into

```
times1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
values = [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4.333, 5,  6]
```

These values are calculated according to this plot from the intermediate values:

[image]

Of course I could make a loop to find these values and stuff them into a target array. But I wonder if numpy has something to do that "at once".

NB: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961787/reshape-array-on-xaxis-and-fill-with-mean-value-in-python) is similar to what I want (though a bit more trivial), so I guess that there is nothing out of the box. But who knows.

Comment: Show us how you would do it in the loop.

Comment: times1 and values don't have the same number of elements. It seems like you are looking for interpolation though. scipy has functions for that. With pandas, it would be easier.

Comment: @ayhan You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With scipy, you can use [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d    
f = interp1d(times, values)

f(times1)
Out: 
array([ 1.        ,  2.        ,  2.5       ,  3.        ,  4.33333333,
        5.        ,  6.        ])
```

With pandas, this is also possible:

```
ser = pd.Series(values, index=times)
ser2 = pd.Series(index=times1)

ser.combine_first(ser2).interpolate(method='index').reindex(ser2.index)
Out: 
0    1.000000
1    2.000000
2    2.500000
3    3.000000
4    4.333333
5    5.000000
6    6.000000
dtype: float64
```

`combine_first` takes the union of the both indices. interpolate is the main method that does the job. Since you are doing a linear interpolation on the indices, you need to pass `method='index'`.

Comment: I'd love to test that, but for now I get 'module' object has no attribute 'interpolate'.  Just used pip to upgrade which seemed to be recommended in that case. Else this would exactly be what I need.

Comment: @ThomasKilian It seems it was added in version 0.14. Does `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d`  work?

Comment: It does :-) Pandas also works. Saved me a lot of loops :-)